# Chosen get multiple selected values without jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-chosen

In [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) I get multi-selected values using the following code in `jQuery` -

```
$("chosen-selector").chosen().val()
```

But if I want to get these multiple selected values of `select` within a `form` via `PHP` it gives only single option value -

```
$multiple_values = $_REQUEST['chosen_select_name']
```

`$multiple_values` variable returns only a single value. How can I get multiple selected values using `PHP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make this field as array so that php can understand you will be passing multiple values. in html part make your field name from "chosen_select_name" to "chosen_select_name[]" and check the request.

Multi select behavior works same as checkbox logic.